log4net TelNetAppender : ObjectDisposedException with log4net 3.0
I recently migrated my (C#) windows application to the version 3 of log4net. And I've now an exception when my application start : "System.ObjectDisposedException: 'Cannot access a disposed object.
Object name: 'System.Net.Sockets.Socket'.'" (see screenshot below)
The port that I use is not locked by another application, because if I rollback my changes and run my application with previous version of log4net (v2.0.1) => it's works fine.
Is something change between log4net v2.0.1 and v3 ?
My config:
<!-- Telnet appender for human monitoring -->
<appender name="TelnetAppender" type="log4net.Appender.TelnetAppender">
    <port value="4061" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date{HH:mm:ss.fff} %-5level - %message%newline" />
    </layout>
</appender>



Have you tried 3.0.1

@stuartd: yes I tried with the latest version

@VyTre I'm responsible for log4net an tried to reproduce your issue:
https://github.com/apache/logging-log4net/blob/Feature/TelnetBug/src/log4net.Tests/Appender/TelnetAppenderTest.cs
Can you take a look at the test and (maybe) make it fail?
It would also be a good idea to create an issue under
https://github.com/apache/logging-log4net/issues

@Jan: Hi Jan,
I tried to run the UnitTest (TelnetAppenderTest) in Execution mode : OK, no error.
But when I try to run it in debug, I have the same issue (but at the end). When the test tries to dispose the Telnet Client, an error "Cannot access a disposed object" appears (see screenshot link below). It's the issue that I have.
https://snipboard.io/Dnb8Vj.jpg
I migrated two applications : both have the same issue

One at the end, when the application are being to be dispose
The 2nd have the issue at the startup


Issue created: https://github.com/apache/logging-log4net/issues/194

A TelnetAppender bug regression with log4net v3.0.1
Bug fixed with version 3.0.2-preview
